# How to use variable names when grep and sed are combined?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to search for a string and replace it with different string in all files in a directory recursively. I am able to use sed on one file like this and it works:

```
sed -i "s|${searchStr}|${replaceStr}|g" "${rootDir}"file.cs
```

But when I am using it with grep, i am not seeing the changes in the files or getting any error messages.

**This Works:**

```
grep -rnlis --include=*.{html,css,js,aspx} './' -e "/images/" |
 xargs -i@ sed -i "s|/images/|https://example.com/Images/|I" @
```

**Tried these but did not work:**

```
searchStr='/images/'
replaceStr='https://example.com/Images/'
...  -e "$searchStr" | xargs -i@ sed -i "s|$searchStr|$replaceStr|I" @
```

and

```
...  -e "${searchStr}" | xargs -i@ sed -i "s|${searchStr}|${replaceStr}|I" @
```

**Error Messages** when used with Variable Names in the expression:

`: No such file or directoryult.js`

`: No such file or directoryders.aspx`

`: No such file or directoryork.css`

`: No such file or directoryal-power.js`

How do I use variables names instead of hardcoding?

Environment: cygwin (so Windows GNU sed /grep)

Comment: I'd like to see how you assign searchStr.

Comment: @Kotshi, I modified the question. Please check

Comment: Does it work when you put the literal strings in instead of variables?

Comment: @123 yes, it works when i put literal strings as i have mentioned tiltled "this works". But i want to use variables in case I have more operations to do later

Comment: I think you forgot a '/' in searchStr (Don't think it could solve the case).

Comment: @Kotshi thanks, it was a copy paste error. Updated the question. But yes, that is not the problem

Comment: What if you leave out the sed? Does grep itself return any result? You should break down the pipeline when it doesn't work.

Comment: Theres no way that if the literal one works the variables won't. You must have a typo somewhere or something.

Comment: I don't think `grep` supports brace expansion in `--include=*.{html,css,js,aspx}`.  You should also quote the wildcard to prevent the shell from expanding it.

Comment: Your example uses `/g` while the script has `/I`.  Is that even a valid option for your `sed`?  (You should not need a `/g` flag unless you expect multiple matches per line.)

Comment: If you change the command to `echo sed` you should see that the problem is not with the variable interpolations.

Comment: @tripleee `--include=*.{html,css,js,aspx}` uses shell expansion, and expands to multiple include flags, try it. `I` is case insensitive in sed.

Comment: Ah, true.  There is still the theoretical case of the shell expanding the whole thing when you don't want to, but that would only happen if you have files matching `--include=*`... in the current directory.

Comment: @4ae1e1 @123 @tripleee shell expansion for ```--include=*.{html,css,js,aspx}``` works fine, as I can see the replace happening when searchStr and replaceStr are hardcoded. It doesn't work when I use variables.

Comment: @tripleee, ```/I``` is for case insensitive match and replace in sed

Comment: do you try with an `export searchStr='/images/';export replaceStr='https://example.com/Images/'`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu when I am declaring the strings and using those variable names in the expression, I am getting 4 errors ( each one for one of the file type) - No such file or directory found. Tried exporting, same errors

Comment: could you try with different separator `#` instead of `|` that have special meaning in sed pattern

Comment: @NeronLeVelu still the same. I used ```|``` instead of ```/``` to avoid escaping each ```/``` because ```searchStr``` and ```replaceStr``` can contain ```/```

Comment: yes, i know why :-). I test from here and no problem neither with both separator, any variable content (except separator itself). with sub folder, under bash, ksh and no problem on my opensuse. what about `| xargs -i@  sed -i "s|${searchStr}|${replaceStr}|I" "@" `

Comment: in fact why the `n` in your grep option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93965/discussion-between-kishorer747-and-neronlevelu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NeronLeVelu, here is the solution:

`searchStr='/images/'
replaceStr='https://example.com/Images/'
grep -rnlis --include=*.{html,css,js,aspx} "$rootDir" -e "/images/" | while read File; do sed -i "s|${searchStr}|${replaceStr}|I" "${File}"; done`

It works perfectly and replacing the searchStr in rootDir recursively.